# Android audio manager method causing a force close

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

New to this and a bit confused as to why calling the following method creates a force close:

```
AudioManager myaudiomanager;

public void toggleSilent()
{
  myaudiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

I don't see any blatant errors and I have added permissions to the manifest regarding the audio manager.

Anyone able to direct me further?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at the Java stack trace associated with the error, to learn where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The object is never created first of all. Try that.

```
myaudiomanager = new AudioManager();
// Not sure what parameters are needed but the documentation in the audiomanager tag has it.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you posted the ADB log that might help..

A force close usually means your main thread is not responding, or more specifically not withing the alotted time of Android.  I find it hard to believe a call into the AudioManager is causing a FC..